# Entity Framework - Composite Primary key, two foreign keys, DB First not generating model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have been trying to handle translations in my database and also Entity Framework. I am generating the following tables but the translate model is not being generated by Entity Framework. I have tried numerous combinations but it won't generate. But, for some reason there is one `LanguageTranslate` model that IS being generated I think it's because there is just a regular primary key and only one foreign key.

Any ideas are very welcome? Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Merchant] 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
    -- Other columns here
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MerchantTranslate]
(
    [MerchantId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [LanguageId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Name] NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MerchantTranslate] 
        PRIMARY KEY ([MerchantId], [LanguageId]), 

    CONSTRAINT [FK_MerchantTranslate_ToMerchant] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MerchantId]) REFERENCES [Merchant]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MerchantTranslate_ToLanguage] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([LanguageId]) REFERENCES [Language]([Id]) 
)
```